# A question on the Kodaira dimension of 3-folds

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, birational-geometry, divisors, kodaira-dimension

Let $X$ a smooth projective $3$-fold. Assume that $X$ admits a finite rational map $f:X\dashrightarrow Y$ where $Y$ is a smooth Calabi-Yau 3-fold, and a fibration $g:X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^2$ with a smooth curve of positive Kodaira dimension as general fiber.

Under these hypothesis what can we say on the Kodaira dimension of $X$ ?

Comment: Not much. The second condition is essentially trivial (take any sufficiently ample line bundle $L$ on $X$, and any general plane in $\mid L\mid$). The first one just tells you that the Kodaira dimension is nonnegative.